# Why is my code not recognizing the addActionListener(ActionListener e) method?

Tags: java, events, import, awt, actionlistener

### My Problem

Compiling this class in NetBeans for Java. I'm trying to simply add an ActionListener to each JPanel. However, when I type in the code:

```
 `addActionListener(new SquareMouseListener);`
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot Find Symbol;
    method addActionListener(MinePanel.SquareMouseListener)
    location: class MinePanel
```

#### Here is the full code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MinePanel extends JPanel{
final private int xPos, yPos;
final private int numXPanels, numYPanels;
final private boolean isBomb;

private MineFrame holderFrame;
private boolean seen;

public MinePanel(int xPos, int yPos, int numXPanels, int numYPanels, MineFrame holderFrame)
{
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.numXPanels = numXPanels;
    this.numYPanels = numYPanels;
    if(Math.random()<.1)
    {
        isBomb = true;
    }
    else isBomb = false;
    seen = false;

    this.holderFrame = holderFrame;
    addActionListener(new SquareMouseListener());

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    //Color thisColor = new Color((float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random());
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(1,1,getWidth()-2,getHeight()-2);
}


private class SquareMouseListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        System.out.println("Action Performed");
    }
}
}
```

What can I do? Netbeans tells me to import:

```
import static com.sun.java.accessibility.util.AWTEventMonitor.addActionListener;
```

but I know that's not right because I tried it and it didn't work, and because addActionListener should be included in java.awt.event.*; import above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because MinePanel or JPanel doesn't define it

Answer (score 2):

Just type `this.add` and press ctrl + space. You will see what type of listeners you can add to JPanel.
Probably you are needing the MouseListener.

`this.addMouseListener(new YourListener());`

where `YourListener` implements `MouseListener` interface.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was, and I wanted to post an answer in case anyone else was looking.

The problem exists in trying to add an *ActionListener* to a JPanel, which cannot be done. There is no predefined addActionListener() method for JPanel because it is meant as a lower level component. As @Jigar Joshi i said, JPanel does not define Action Listener events.

Thanks everyone for the help!